# How to remove only those commas which are present inside double quotes in a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### The Current String (below)

153,Rajashekar,9/13/2021,06-01-1988,33,98%,NAD,NAD,NAD,NAD,not applicable in view of covid-19,NAD,NAD,**"Patient in good health, ready to discharge"**, Not in Particulars,10,Pale Yellow,Clear,Nil,Nil,Both eyes simple myopia,Normal,Reports Shared,Normal,Reports Attached,WNL,
**"Uncontrolled hypertension: Salt Restricted Diet, Regular walk, Monitor blood pressure regularly ( once in 15 days ), Cardiologist opinion with further evaluation. Pertain to vision, advised glass prescription distance vision. "**,
*Conditional Fit,Yes to work.

## Expected output:

153,Rajashekar,9/13/2021,06-01-1988,33,98%,NAD,NAD,NAD,NAD,not applicable in view of covid-19,NAD,NAD,**"Patient in good health ready to discharge"**, Not in Particulars,10,Pale Yellow,Clear,Nil,Nil,Both eyes simple myopia,Normal,Reports Shared,Normal,Reports Attached,WNL,
**"Uncontrolled hypertension: Salt Restricted Diet Regular walk Monitor blood pressure regularly ( once in 15 days ) Cardiologist opinion with further evaluation. Pertain to vision advised glass prescription distance vision. "**,
*Conditional Fit,Yes to work.

### Note

*As you can see there are lots of commas in this big string, I want to remove commas from only those sub-strings which contain double quotes here (in bold text).*

Comment: This has the distinct scent of an XY Problem! Are you trying to actually parse a CSV and the commas which are not delimiters are causing you problems? If so, use a proper CSV parser and dont try to do it yourself.

Comment: @Jamiec yes, im using a csv for this case, any suggestions for better approach or may be a link would be helpful.

Comment: im fetching this content from a input tag in react, like this `let files = myFile
            const formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('files[]', files[0])
            const reader = new FileReader()
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                let contents = e.target.result

                const csvGeneratedData = csvHandler(contents)
                console.log("csvGeneratedData", csvGeneratedData)
                csvDataHandler(csvGeneratedData)`

Comment: Since this is a React application, you can (and should) use some npm module to parse the string as a raw CSV input

Comment: Is that fake data or are you divulging Rajashekar's personal medical data?

Comment: @Wyck its fake :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the double quotes would always be balanced, you could try a regex replacement with a callback function:

```js
var input = "A,B,\"foo, bar\",D";
var output = input.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, (x) => x.replace(/,/g, ""));
console.log(input);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: thanks a lot this is just what I needed. Also, you missed the global tag in the first replace section. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const stringToClean = `153,Rajashekar B Hanchinal,9/13/2021,06-01-1988,33,M3249,M,9739465908,RIPL,Manufacturing Assistant,Starch,168,67,24,Normal Weight,B+Ve,160,100,76,93,88,A Small black mole present over the Rt.hand palm,8 Years,Vegetarian,NAD,Nil in particular,NAD,NAD,HTN,Nil in particular,No,98%,NAD,NAD,NAD,NAD,not applicable in view of covid-19,NAD,NAD,"Patient in good health, ready to discharge", Not in Particulars,10,Pale Yellow,Clear,Nil,Nil,Both eyes simple myopia,Normal,Reports Shared,Normal,Reports Attached,WNL, "Uncontrolled hypertension: Salt Restricted Diet, Regular walk, Monitor blood pressure regularly ( once in 15 days ), Cardiologist opinion with further evaluation. Pertain to vision, advised glass prescription distance vision. ", *Conditional Fit,Yes to work.`
const result = s.replace(/"[^"]+"/g, function(v) { 
      return v.replace(/,/g, '');
});
console.log(result) //153,Rajashekar B Hanchinal,9/13/2021,06-01-1988,33,M3249,M,9739465908,RIPL,Manufacturing Assistant,Starch,168,67,24,Normal Weight,B+Ve,160,100,76,93,88,A Small black mole present over the Rt.hand palm,8 Years,Vegetarian,NAD,Nil in particular,NAD,NAD,HTN,Nil in particular,No,98%,NAD,NAD,NAD,NAD,not applicable in view of covid-19,NAD,NAD,"Patient in good health ready to discharge", Not in Particulars,10,Pale Yellow,Clear,Nil,Nil,Both eyes simple myopia,Normal,Reports Shared,Normal,Reports Attached,WNL, "Uncontrolled hypertension: Salt Restricted Diet Regular walk Monitor blood pressure regularly ( once in 15 days ) Cardiologist opinion with further evaluation. Pertain to vision advised glass prescription distance vision. ", *Conditional Fit,Yes to work.
```

Comment: This answer is almost identical to mine, and was posted 5 minutes later.